# String class assignment operator (+=) behaves weirdly

Tags: c++

I have this code behaving weirdly:

```
int main() {

    string a = "TRY";
    string b = "THIS";

    a += b[0] + '!';      //This outputs "TRYu"?
    //a = a + b[0] + '!'; //This outputs "TRYT!" as expected.

    cout << a;

}
```

Shouldn't the above two statements be the same?

Comment: Think about what `b[0] + '!'` does.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Your first example is not equal to

```
a = a + b[0] + '!'
```

But rather to

```
a = a + ( b[0] + '!' )
```

You know that a char is a numeric value. Since both `b[0]` and `'!'` are chars, `b[0] + '!'` will NOT give you a concatenation but an addition (`b[0] + 33`, basically). Then you will try to append the ASCII character of code `b[0] + 33` into your string. Since `b[0]` is `'T'` (ASCII 84), you end up with the character of ASCII code 117 : `'u'`.

You will have to replace `'!'` by `std::string("!")` to fix the code and make a concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

No, `char + char = char;`

`std::string + char = std::string;`

In your second example.

`a = a + b[0] + '!';`

would be

`string = ((string + char) + char)`

Where you are always adding something to a `std::string` object

Answer (score 1):

In

```
a += b[0] + '!';
```

the `b[0] + '!'` part is evaluated first. As `b[0]` is a char and '!' is a char (primitive type), the `+` operator adds them arithmetically to produce another char, which is then appended to the string with the `+=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

b[0] is just a char. So b[0] + '1' is char + char, that's no good. Built-In types don't have any fancy stuff going on like strings do, they just add the values. ;) In the second (working) example the b[0] gets added to a and then '!' gets added to that, so there always the string operator is used.